# Finding the shortest path between two rotations (in degrees)

Tags: java

I am trying to find the shortest "path" between two rotations, measured in degrees.

Example problem:
I am given two rotations: `10` and `340`. The shortest path between these rotations would be `-30`, because going below 0 degrees underflows to 359 degrees. However, I seem to be unable to get the value programmatically! Everything i've tried before (lots of random code snippets), always returned the longer path, which would be `330` with this example.

Short problem version:

- Rotation A: `10`
- Rotation B: `340`
- Shortest path: `-30`
- Longest path: `330`
- I am unable to find the logic to compute the shortest path, which is my goal.

XY Problem addendum:
I am working on game project. For this matter, i have an entity that moves through 3D-space. That movement is determined by a 3D-vector. The entity also has yaw and pitch. In the previously described example problem, `Rotation A` is the yaw that the entity currently has. `Rotation B` is the yaw of the current movement vector. The entity is supposed to slowly adjust its yaw to match the current vector.

I am coding this project using Java.

Thank you!

Comment: Does this help: [Smallest difference between two angles?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6722272/smallest-difference-between-two-angles) Although the code is C#, I believe you can adapt it to your needs.

Comment: Does this help: [How can I find the difference between two angles?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1878907/how-can-i-find-the-difference-between-two-angles)

Comment: Here's one with Java code: [How do I calculate the difference of two angle measures?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7570808/how-do-i-calculate-the-difference-of-two-angle-measures)

Comment: Thank you guys! I am sure to find my answer in those. I assure you that i tried to web-search an answer before opening my own question - it seems like my phrasing was just way off, otherwise i should have found these. Thanks again --- i marked this question as duplicate